# Why my colors is not output on the screen under a rafce react environtment

Tags: reactjs

> I am using react rafce function and I want to decorate my color icons ,I decided to create a rounded icons with colors inside but it ended up not showing any colors.

> This is my css styling

```
const FilterColor = styled.div`
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:$props{props=>props.color};
    margin:0px 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
`
```

> This is my html code

```
    <FilterTitle>Color: </FilterTitle>
    <FilterColor color= 'red' />
    <FilterColor  color ='darkblue'/>
    <FilterColor color='orange' />
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz45t.png)

[This is what it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSlkH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you are using styled-components, change your FilterColor component to:

```
const FilterColor = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.color}; // <-- this got changed
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

Comment: Yes I made it! Thank you and btw I forget to mention that I used styled-components.My bad.